# Query All Tables In A Database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am surely just askewing my and statement here.  I want to get a list of all tables that meet both conditions (but it returns 0).  If I run each statement individually they each return multiple tables, but adding the and into the query 0 tables are returned (which I know is incorrect).  What do I need to change to get this to execute successfully?

**Works**

```
select 
    table_name, column_name
from  
    information_schema.columns 
where 
    column_name ILIKE 'Man%'
```

**Works**

```
select 
    table_name, column_name
from 
    information_schema.columns 
where 
    column_name ILIKE 'sale%'
```

**Returns 0 results**

```
select 
    table_name, column_name
from 
    information_schema.columns 
where 
    (column_name ILIKE 'man%'
     and column_name ILIKE 'sale%')
order by 
    table_name asc
```

I want to return tables that have a column that begins with `man` AND a column that begins with `sale` only. Is there a way to achieve this result?

Comment: Not familiar with postgresql but you can't query a single column like two separate things using AND. I would perform a self join on the table columns

Comment: @Simon how would I use a Self Join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
select a.table_name,a.column_Name,b.column_Name from 
(select table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name ILIKE 'Man%') a,
(select table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name ILIKE 'sale%')b
where a.table_name=b.table_name
order by a.table_name asc
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said, I'm not familiar with postgresql so this may not work. :)

```
select a.table_name, a.column_name, b.column_name
from information_schema.columns a
join information_schema.columns b on a.table_name=b.table_name
where (a.column_name ILIKE 'man%'
AND b.column_name ILIKE 'sale%')
ORDER BY table_name ASC
```